# How to do negative binomial regression with the rms package in R?

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

How can I use the `rms` package in R to execute a negative binomial regression? ([I originally posted this question on Statistics SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538466/how-to-do-negative-binomial-regression-with-the-rms-package-in-r), but it was closed apparently because it is a better fit here.)

With the `MASS` package, I use the `glm.nb` function, but I am trying to switch to the `rms` package because I sometimes get weird errors when bootstrapping with `glm.nb` and some other functions. But I cannot figure out how to do a negative binomial regression with the `rms` package.

Here is sample code of what I would like to do (copied from the `rms::Glm` function documentation):

```
library(rms)
## Dobson (1990) Page 93: Randomized Controlled Trial :
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
f <- Glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family=poisson())

f
anova(f)
summary(f, outcome=c('1','2','3'), treatment=c('1','2','3'))
```

So, instead of using `family=poisson()`, I would like to use something like `family=negative.binomial()`, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

In the documentation for `family {stats}`, I found this note in the "See also" section:

> For binomial coefficients, choose; the binomial and negative binomial distributions, Binomial, and NegBinomial.

But even after clicking the link for `?NegBinomial`, I cannot make any sense of this.

I would appreciate any help on how to use the `rms` package in R to execute a negative binomial regression.

Comment: See the answer below @Tripartio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**opinion up front** You might be better off posting (as a separate question) a reproducible example of the "weird errors" from your bootstrap attempts and seeing whether people have ideas for resolving them. It's fairly common for NB fitting procedures to throw warnings or errors when data are equi- or underdispersed, as the estimates of the dispersion parameter become infinite in this case ...

@coffeinjunky is correct that using `family = negative.binomial(theta=VALUE)` will work (where `VALUE` is a numeric constant, e.g. `theta=1` for the geometric distribution [a special case of the NB]). **However**: you won't be able (without significantly more work) be able to fit the general NB model, i.e. the model where the dispersion parameter (theta) is estimated as part of the fitting procedure. That's what `MASS::glm.nb` does, and AFAICS there is no analogue in the `rms` package.

There are a few other packages/functions in addition to `MASS::glm.nb` that fit the negative binomial model, including (at least) `bbmle` and `glmmTMB` — there may be others such as `gamlss`.

```r
## Dobson (1990) Page 93: Randomized Controlled Trial :
dd < data.frame(
   counts = c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
   outcome = gl(3,1,9),
   treatment = gl(3,3))
```

### MASS::glm.nb

```r
library(MASS)
m1 <- glm.nb(counts ~ outcome + treatment, data = dd)
## "iteration limit reached" warning
```

### glmmTMB

```r
library(glmmTMB)
m2 <- glmmTMB(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = nbinom2, data = dd)
## "false convergence" warning
```

### bbmle

```r
library(bbmle)
m3 <- mle2(counts ~ dnbinom(mu = exp(logmu), size = exp(logtheta)),
     parameters = list(logmu ~outcome + treatment),
     data = dd,
     start = list(logmu = 0, logtheta = 0)
)
```

```r
signif(cbind(MASS=coef(m1), glmmTMB=fixef(m2)$cond, bbmle=coef(m3)[1:5]), 5)
                   MASS     glmmTMB       bbmle
(Intercept)  3.0445e+00  3.04540000  3.0445e+00
outcome2    -4.5426e-01 -0.45397000 -4.5417e-01
outcome3    -2.9299e-01 -0.29253000 -2.9293e-01
treatment2  -1.1114e-06  0.00032174  8.1631e-06
treatment3  -1.9209e-06  0.00032823  6.5817e-06
```

These all agree fairly well (at least for the intercept/outcome parameters). This example is fairly difficult for a NB model (5 parameters + dispersion for 9 observations, data are Poisson rather than NB).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf), the following seems to work:

```
library(rms)
library(MASS)

counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)

Glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = negative.binomial(theta = 1))
General Linear Model
 
 rms::Glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = negative.binomial(theta = 1))
 
                    Model Likelihood    
                          Ratio Test    
    Obs       9    LR chi2      0.31    
 Residual d.f.4    d.f.            4    
    g 0.2383063    Pr(> chi2) 0.9892    
 
             Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
 Intercept    3.0756 0.2121 14.50  <0.0001 
 outcome=2   -0.4598 0.2333 -1.97  0.0487  
 outcome=3   -0.2962 0.2327 -1.27  0.2030  
 treatment=2 -0.0347 0.2333 -0.15  0.8819  
 treatment=3 -0.0503 0.2333 -0.22  0.8293
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; I was on vacation. I am pretty sure that theta == 1 is not what I am looking for. As the article you linked explains, that is a simplistic assumption for the geometric model. MASS::glm.nb is able to estimate the theta automatically. My question is essentially how to run negative binomial using the rms package when theta is not known beforehand (because it is pretty much never known beforehand).